it shows the message that Script execution completed. but result not found
I have following script written and my worksheet has following headers but it still does not show anything as a result. it shows only a message

Script execution completed.

but result not found
The header in a first raw of my google spreadsheet is
Sr. Area    code    Name    Mobile  Exam    Zone    Grade-6 % of 6  Paper-6 Grade-5 % of 5  Paper-5 Grade-4 % of 4  Paper-4 Grade-3 % of 3  Paper-3 Grade-2 % of 2  Paper-2 Grade-1 % of 1  Paper-1

</html>`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Exam Details Lookup</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Enter Your Exam Code:</h1>
  <input type="text" id="examCode">
  <button onclick="getExamDetails()">Get Details</button>
  <div id="details"></div>

  <script>
    function getExamDetails() {
      var examCode = document.getElementById('examCode').value;
      var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxseOIk6y-KvqRP0jomMoldMflG7sEX0vDRVpF-dZpmwaL6tg0S5QvR8kDWL52-pcPAhg/exec?examCode=' + encodeURIComponent(examCode);

      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          var detailsDiv = document.getElementById('details');
          detailsDiv.innerHTML = '';

          if (data) {
            for (var key in data) {
              detailsDiv.innerHTML += '<strong>' + key + ':</strong> ' + data[key] + '<br>';
            }
          } else {
            detailsDiv.textContent = 'No details found for the provided exam code.';
          }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

please suggest how to resolve

Please include full details of the error you're getting - it's very hard to know what the issue is without them.

What is an example code? And who wrote the actual script you are executing on the sheet and how does it look?

@JoeClay The script returns the string Script execution completed.  without errors.
